# How to shorten a single resourceful Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

So, I have the following in `routes.rb`:

```
scope(path_names: { new: "register" }) do
  resources :accounts
end
```

This works, as it generates a `/accounts/register` route, but would like to change it to simply say `/register`. I know I could use `match "/register" => "accounts#new"`, but I am wondering if there is a *better* way to accomplish this, as this would still leave the `/accounts/register` route "open". I could probably rename it to something obscure by using `{new: "pygmy_puff"}`, but I am not confident if it's the right approach.

I'd really like to do this right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
match "/register" => "accounts#new"
# ...
 scope(path_names: { new: "register" }) do
  resources :accounts, :except => :new
end
```

In that order.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't sweat the extra route, and use the extra match statement.  Looking forward to rails 4, though I think it would be better written with the http method:

```
get "/register" => "accounts#new"
```